# list of connected mac addresses through wifi

Tags: android, wifi, mac-address, arp

I really need help for a android program.

Please can anybody tell me anyway in which i could get the list of connected mac addresses through wifi. I already tried arp but it  gives false results if the arp file is't refreshed

Answer (score 0):

It is called Android Network Discovery and interested developers can get its source code from 
Android network tool: Discover hosts and scan their ports, in your Wifi/3G network.
http://bit.ly/QrIwLB